# 404 not found when trying to change nginx webserver location

Tags: nginx, localhost, nginx-location

I'm using nginx in linux ubuntu as my webservice and the default index.php for my localhost is in the `/www/var/html`. I'm trying ti change it to other directory, which is `/root/user/web/html`. My configuration at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name _ localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
```

however, when i tried to change `root /var/www/html;` to `root /root/user/web/html;` the localhost said **404 Not Found** (i have already checked the path of directory i want to use using pwd command and it resulted /root/user/web/html). Is there anything i could change or do in order to fix this? Thankyou

Comment: Check each directory in the path (`root`, `user`, `web` and `html`) and ensure that the process running Nginx has read access.

Comment: each of the directories in the path has `drwxr-xr-x` permissions

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that the `server` block is as described in your question. Check the access log to ensure that this server is processing the request and returning 404. Check the error log, and if empty, comment out the line `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`, restart Nginx, solicit a 404 response and check the error log again - this should indicate the cause of the error. Failing all that, use `curl -I` to solicit a 404 response, and check the headers to see if PHP rather than Nginx is generating the response.

Answer (score 3):

### Issue with file permissions

Sometimes, it's an issue with file permissions. The user in your `user` directive should at least have read and write permissions to the file you're trying to access.

#### The following is a fix for this issue

*nginx can be any user in the ff example*

example:

```
user nginx;


server {
    root /root/user/web/html;
}
```

`groups nginx` to check the group of nginx.
In my system, I've grouped nginx to www-data group. This is the output: `nginx: www-data`. 1st part is the user and 2nd part is the group.

`ls -al /root/user/web/html` to see if nginx owns the folder
It should output this:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 nginx www-data 4.0K Aug 24 14:52 .
drwxr-x--- 4 root     root     4.0K Aug 23 17:16 ..
-rwxr-x--- 1 nginx www-data   24 Aug 24 14:26 index.html (or some other file)
... Some more files
```

[This guide shows the basics of file permissions](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions)
But a summary of this:
3rd column is the owner. If it's the same as the `user` directive, the first row should have `drwx` in its 1st column, which means that `/var/www/html` is a directory (`d`) owned by `nginx` with `r`ead, `w`rite, and e`x`ecute permissions.

The following `r-x` means that the group (4th column which is `www-data` in my case) have `r`ead and e`x`ecute permissions, but no `w`rite permissions. If the folder is not owned by the user in the nginx `user` directive, the folder should be owned by the same group that the user (`nginx`) is in which is `www-data` in my case.

And the last `---` means that other users don't have any permissions at all.

[Here's a guide in updating file permissions](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/right-folder-permission-website)
Or a summary:
*Replace `nginx` with your desired user and `www-data` with your desired group*

```
chown -R nginx /root/user/web/html/
chgrp -R www-data /root/user/web/html/
chmod -R 750 /root/user/web/html/
chmod g+s /root/user/web/html/
```

This should work if the user has read permissions in the folders that lead to /html/, which are /root/, user/, and web/